# Vuejs image url link

Tags: vue.js

Hi I am really new to vuejs. I try to import a picture then call this picture in the methods.

```
import image from '@/assets/svg/xxx.svg'
```

then in the data

```
data () {
        return {
            image: image
        }
    },
```

and try to use it

```
li.style.backgroundImage = "url('this.image')";
```

But the image is not showing, and image link show as following

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/order/detail/29/this.image
```

I really not sure where i get wrong...Please help...

Comment: You should simple use the path to the image in your js. That would be
`li.style.backgroundImage = "url('/static/assets/svg/xxx.svg')"`

Comment: unquote to parameter: `"url(this.image)"`

Comment: If I use "url('/static/assets/svg/xxx.svg')" It show the link with order/detail/static/assets/svg/xxx.svg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A another way to doing it using computed property on style attribute :

```
computed : {
    liStyle(){
        return "background-image : url('" + require('@/assets/svg/xxx.svg') + "')";
    }
}
```

Template :

```
<li :style="liStyle"></li>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! This is working for me...May i ask you why there got "+" ??? like " + require('@/assets/svg/xxx.svg') + "

Comment: Concatenation, allowing webpack to compute le path to the resource (via require function).

Answer (score 3):

I think the better (and scalable) solution it's to have a class which sets the styles you want, and add it to the elements, if it have to be dinamically, just add it with `:class` on some condition.

**note**: i used an external image path, but it's the same with your local path. And use `require()` to import images and html

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example'
})
```

```css
.li-with-bg-image {
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example">
  <ul>
    <li :class="{'li-with-bg-image': true}"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="li-with-bg-image"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Another options**

Using inline styles (using v-bind:style)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example">
  <ul>
    <li :style="`background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150')`"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Using data section or a computed property binded to style

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    myStyles: `background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150')`
  },
  computed: {
    anotherStyles () { 
      return `background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/300x150')`
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example">
  <ul>
    <li :style="myStyles"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li :style="anotherStyles"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Resources:

[Class and style bindings Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

Comment: Thanks your help! but my problem is to find the image url. It always to add extra link..For example...if i set image url = @/assets/svg/xxx.svg, Then showing on the page url = http://127.0.0.1:8080/order/detail/xxx, then when it render, the image url will be http://127.0.0.1:8080/order/detail/assets/svg/xxx.svg..which is the page link + image link...of course, it won't show the picture because the picture is not in that folder. I need call the picture in vue methods, because I want to check the uploaded file type then update the different thumb icon

Comment: user require() to import it

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't import an image via the import statement, only modules (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

I would recommend reading up on the [Vue-Webpack-template](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/) and look at the [static assets section](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html).

In short you could use Webpack (or Gulp) to move your assets to a fixed location and then use links.

Comment: Thanks a lot your help..I am sure that the current project is already using webpack...So I think this is the reason the picture rending with page_url + image_url...I will read the static assets..I think it will help me to understand... But i solve the problem by using computed with liStyling...then call liStyling in the methods...